Flutter SQLite connection trouble (for Android)
Doing app for Android.(new on flutter) Trying to connect to already existing SQLite file to project.
I have issue with connection, it doesnt connecting to file but init empty new one with same name in drirectory of android (Android/data/com.exemple.android_studio_project). In enternet i have seen only lazy initialization variant. There was some methods to locate file, but for some reason they dont working.
I tried to ask AI but answer wasnt satisfy me.
**True db location is:
D:\android_studio_project\lib\souece.db **
part of the code sqLite_connect.dart:
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart'; 
import 'dart:io'; 

class SqliteConnect {
  static final SqliteConnect instance = SqliteConnect._init();

  SqliteConnect._init();

  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;


    _database = await _initDB('source.db');
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

   
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, filePath);

   
    bool dbExists = await _checkDbExists(path);

   
    if (!dbExists) {
      await _copyDbFromAssets(path);
    }

   
    return await openDatabase(path);
  }

  
  Future<bool> _checkDbExists(String path) async {
    try {
      return await File(path).exists();
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }


  Future<void> _copyDbFromAssets(String path) async {

    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('android_studio_project/assets/source.db');


    List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);

    
    await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  }






}

I expexting to take data from the file that be in the app
If theer is technology of storing data in sqlite on Flutter app that i dont know, i will be glad to take advise.

The database file you are bundling with your app cannot be in the lib folder. It needs to be a Flutter asset, and this document describes where to store a file as an asset, and how to let Flutter know it is there. The function _copyDbFromAssets in your code copies a bundled asset to the application's documents directory, where it can be accessed by sqlite.
